# AngularUI router issue "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have a set of DIV's that contain A's and use AngularUI to load Angular templates within a ui-view DIV. I'm implementing a set of tabs that switch between the view templates based on which one a user clicks. I have several of these within the application and all work as designed. However, on one of my pages I keep getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" that blows up in the angular-ui-router isMatch() call in the $StateRefActiveDirective($state, $stateParams, $interpolate) function on the line 'return $state.includes(state.name) && matchesParams();' because state is not defined. I've stepped through the calls to this code and it processes all of the ui-srefs in my markup successfully. Then after those are processed it gags.
The only real difference between other pages with these tabs on them is that I have the other pages with no other markup on them except the tabs and their ui-views. On this one I have 2 bootstrap columns, a col-md-5 and col-md-7. The col-md-5 contains a table of objects. When the user clicks on one of the rows the col-md-7 is shown, the $state is changed to one of its tabs and the data for the object is loaded for the tab by its controller.
On the other pages the tabs are always displayed and clicking them takes you to different ui-views the same as the my problem child. One real difference between them is a directive I wrote to 'disable' the links based on a Boolean. The uiSrefIf directive is at the bottom of the JavaScript listing. The idea is that when the File tab is shown the other tabs are visible but disabled.

Here is the JavaScript and markup:

```js
angular.module('meritApp.screens.importUsers', [
    'ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select', 'ui.bootstrap', 'meritApp.global.services.profile',
    'meritApp.global.services.common', 'angularFileUpload', 'meritApp.global.services.managedFiles'
  ])
  .config(function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('importUsers', {
        url: "/admin/importUsers",
        templateUrl: "app/screens/admin/importUsers/importUsers.html?v=" + APP_VERSION
      });

    $stateProvider
      .state('importUsers.file', {
        url: "/file",
        templateUrl: "app/screens/admin/importUsers/file.html?v=" + APP_VERSION
      });

    $stateProvider
      .state('importUsers.inserted', {
        url: "/inserted",
        templateUrl: "app/screens/admin/importUsers/inserted.html?v=" + APP_VERSION
      });

    $stateProvider
      .state('importUsers.insertError', {
        url: "/insertError",
        templateUrl: "app/screens/admin/importUsers/insertError.html?v=" + APP_VERSION
      });

    $stateProvider
      .state('importUsers.skipped', {
        url: "/skipped",
        templateUrl: "app/screens/admin/importUsers/skipped.html?v=" + APP_VERSION
      });

    $stateProvider
      .state('importUsers.updated', {
        url: "/updated",
        templateUrl: "app/screens/admin/importUsers/updated.html?v=" + APP_VERSION
      });

  })
  .controller('importUsersController', [
    '$scope', '$state', '$log', '$rootScope', '$filter', 'appConfig', '$http', 'roleSvc',
    function($scope, $state, $log, $rootScope, $filter, appConfig, $http, roleSvc) {

      $rootScope.$broadcast("SET_BREADCRUMB", []);

      $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
      $scope.currentPage = 1;

      $rootScope.importing = false;

      $rootScope.roleChanged = function(user, role) {
        // todo - set the user's role
      };

      $scope.newImport = function() {
        $rootScope.importing = true;
        $rootScope.savedLocation = $rootScope.selectedLocation;
        $rootScope.selectedLocation = null;
      };

      $rootScope.defaultRole = {
        name: "Associate"
      };
      roleSvc.listAllActive(0, 40).then(
        function(response) {
          $rootScope.roles = $filter('orderBy')(response.data.results, "name");
          angular.forEach($rootScope.roles, function(role) {
            if (role.name == "Associate") {
              $rootScope.defaultRole = role;
            }
          });
        },
        function(err) {
          console.log("roleSvc.listAllActive Error: " + err.status + " " + err.statusText);
        });

      var init = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.locations = [];

        var skip = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;
        var userImportQueryPath = "queries/Merit.Components.UserImport.Queries/UserImportQueries";

        $http.get(appConfig.urlRoot + userImportQueryPath + "/GetImportSummaries/results").then(
          function(response) {
            $scope.totalItems = response.data.results.length;
            angular.forEach(response.data.results, function(location) {
              if (skip-- <= 0 && $scope.locations.length < $scope.itemsPerPage) {
                $scope.locations.push(location);
              }
            });

            $scope.loading = false;
          }, function(err) {
            alert("GetImportList Error: " + err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
          });

        $http.get(appConfig.urlRoot + userImportQueryPath + "/GetAuditRecords/results").then(
          function(response) {
            $rootScope.importData = [];
            angular.forEach(response.data.results, function(record) {
              record["isInvited"] = false;
              record["selectedRole"] = $rootScope.defaultRole;
              record.errorText = JSON.parse(record.errorText);
              $rootScope.importData.push(record);
            });

            $scope.users = _.sortBy($rootScope.importData, 'employeeId');
          }, function(err) {
            alert("GetImportList Error: " + err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
          });
      };

      init();

      $scope.refresh = function() {
        init();
      };

      $scope.viewImports = function(location) {
        $rootScope.selectedLocation = location;
        $state.go('importUsers.inserted', {}, {
          reload: true
        });
      };

      $rootScope.closeView = function() {
        $rootScope.importing = false;

        if ($rootScope.savedLocation) {
          $rootScope.selectedLocation = $rootScope.savedLocation;
          $rootScope.savedLocation = null;
        } else {
          $rootScope.selectedLocation = null;
        }
      };

      $scope.inviteUsers = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.users, function(userArray) {
          if (userArray) {
            angular.forEach(userArray, function(user) {
              if (user.isInvited) {
                // todo - send email to invited user
                console.log("Sending email to " + user.name);
                user.isInvited = false;
              }
            });
          }
        });
      };
    }
  ])
  .controller('iuInsertedController', [
    '$scope', '$state', '$log', '$rootScope',
    function($scope, $state, $log, $rootScope) {

      $rootScope.$broadcast("SET_BREADCRUMB", []);

      $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
      $scope.selectedTab = "Inserted";
      $scope.currentPage = 1;
      $scope.inviteCount = 0;

      var init = function() {
        $scope.users = [];
        $scope.totalItems = 0;

        if (!$rootScope.selectedLocation) return;

        var skip = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;

        angular.forEach($rootScope.importData, function(user) {
          if (user.isInserted && !user.hasErrors && user.locationCode == $rootScope.selectedLocation.code && user.timestampUtc == $rootScope.selectedLocation.timeStampUtc) {
            if (skip-- <= 0 && $scope.users.length < $scope.itemsPerPage)
              $scope.users.push(user);

            $scope.totalItems++;
          }
        });
      };

      init();

      $scope.refresh = function() {
        init();
      };

      $scope.invite = function(user) {
        $scope.inviteCount = (user.isInvited ? $scope.inviteCount + 1 : $scope.inviteCount - 1);
      };

      $scope.inviteUsers = function() {
        alert("todo - send email to invited users");

        angular.forEach($scope.users, function(user) {
          if (user.isInvited) {
            // todo - send email to invited user
            console.log("Sending email to " + user.name);
            user.isInvited = false;
          }
        });
      };
    }
  ])
  .controller('iuInsertErrorController', [
    '$scope', '$state', '$log', '$rootScope',
    function($scope, $state, $log, $rootScope) {

      $rootScope.$broadcast("SET_BREADCRUMB", []);

      $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
      $scope.currentPage = 1;
      $scope.selectedTab = "Inserted with Errors";

      var importData = $rootScope.importData;

      var init = function() {
        $scope.users = [];
        $scope.totalItems = 0;

        if (!$rootScope.selectedLocation) return;

        var skip = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;

        angular.forEach(importData, function(user) {
          if (user.isInserted && user.hasErrors && user.locationCode == $rootScope.selectedLocation.code && user.timestampUtc == $rootScope.selectedLocation.timeStampUtc) {
            if (skip-- <= 0 && $scope.users.length < $scope.itemsPerPage)
              $scope.users.push(user);

            $scope.totalItems++;
          }
        });
      };

      init();

      $scope.refresh = function() {
        init();
      };

      $scope.inviteUsers = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.users, function(userArray) {
          if (userArray) {
            angular.forEach(userArray, function(user) {
              if (user.isInvited) {
                // todo - send email to invited user
                console.log("Sending email to " + user.name);
                user.isInvited = false;
              }
            });
          }
        });
      };
    }
  ])
  .controller('iuUpdatedController', [
    '$scope', '$state', '$log', '$rootScope',
    function($scope, $state, $log, $rootScope) {

      $rootScope.$broadcast("SET_BREADCRUMB", []);

      $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
      $scope.currentPage = 1;
      $scope.selectedTab = "Updated";

      var init = function() {
        $scope.users = [];
        $scope.totalItems = 0;

        if (!$rootScope.selectedLocation) return;

        var skip = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;

        angular.forEach($rootScope.importData, function(user) {
          if (user.isUpdated && user.locationCode == $rootScope.selectedLocation.code && user.timestampUtc == $rootScope.selectedLocation.timeStampUtc) {
            if (skip-- <= 0 && $scope.users.length < $scope.itemsPerPage)
              $scope.users.push(user);

            $scope.totalItems++;
          }
        });
      };

      init();

      $scope.refresh = function() {
        init();
      };

      $scope.inviteUsers = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.users, function(userArray) {
          if (userArray) {
            angular.forEach(userArray, function(user) {
              if (user.isInvited) {
                // todo - send email to invited user
                console.log("Sending email to " + user.name);
                user.isInvited = false;
              }
            });
          }
        });
      };
    }
  ])
  .controller('iuSkippedController', [
    '$scope', '$state', '$log', '$rootScope',
    function($scope, $state, $log, $rootScope) {

      $rootScope.$broadcast("SET_BREADCRUMB", []);

      $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
      $scope.currentPage = 1;
      $scope.selectedTab = "Skipped";

      var init = function() {
        $scope.users = [];
        $scope.totalItems = 0;

        if (!$rootScope.selectedLocation) return;

        var skip = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;

        angular.forEach($rootScope.importData, function(user) {
          if (user.wasSkipped && user.locationCode == $rootScope.selectedLocation.code && user.timestampUtc == $rootScope.selectedLocation.timeStampUtc) {
            if (skip-- <= 0 && $scope.users.length < $scope.itemsPerPage)
              $scope.users.push(user);

            $scope.totalItems++;
          }
        });
      };

      init();

      $scope.refresh = function() {
        init();
      };

      $scope.inviteUsers = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.users, function(userArray) {
          if (userArray) {
            angular.forEach(userArray, function(user) {
              if (user.isInvited) {
                // todo - send email to invited user
                console.log("Sending email to " + user.name);
                user.isInvited = false;
              }
            });
          }
        });
      };
    }
  ])
  .controller('iuFileController', [
    '$scope', '$state', '$log', '$rootScope', 'managedFileSvc', 'commandSvc', 'appConfig', '$http', 'modalMsgSvc',
    function($scope, $state, $log, $rootScope, managedFileSvc, commandSvc, appConfig, $http, modalMsgSvc) {

      $rootScope.$broadcast("SET_BREADCRUMB", []);

      $scope.locations = mockExtraLocations;
      $scope.importLocation = undefined;
      $scope.importFile = undefined;
      $scope.buttonText = "Browse...";
      var locationsQueryPath = "queries/Merit.Components.Locations.Queries/LocationQueries";

      $http.get(appConfig.urlRoot + locationsQueryPath + "/FindAllActive/results?skip=" + 0 + "&pageSize=" + 20).then(
        function(response) {
          $scope.locations = response.data.results;
        }, function(err) {
          console.log("LocationQueries.FindAllActive Error: " + err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
        });

      $scope.doImport = function() {
        managedFileSvc.uploadFile($scope.importFile, function(evt) {
          console.log(evt);
          $scope.uploadProgress = evt;
        }, function(response) {
          console.log('upload response :: File ID: ', response[0].QueryReferences[0].QueryParameter);

          var command = {
            ImportFileId: response[0].QueryReferences[0].QueryParameter,
            LocationCode: $scope.importLocation.code,
            LocationName: $scope.importLocation.name
          };

          modalMsgSvc.showLoading("Importing...");

          commandSvc.publish('Merit.Components.User.Commands', 'ImportHumanicUsers', command)
            .then(function(record) {
              modalMsgSvc.hideLoading();
              console.log("ImportHumanicUsers Published: " + record.status);
              $scope.importFile = undefined;
              $rootScope.closeView();
              $state.go("importUsers", {}, {
                reload: true
              });
            }, function(err) {
              modalMsgSvc.hideLoading();
              if (err.errors)
                console.log("ImportHumanicUsers ERROR: " + err.errors[0]);
              else if (err.errorHeadline)
                console.log("ImportHumanicUsers ERROR: " + err.errorHeadline);
              else
                console.log("ImportHumanicUsers ERROR: unknown");
              // TODO?
            });
        });
      };

      $scope.fileSelected = function(files) {
        // even though ng-multiple is false, we still get an array
        if (files != null) {
          $scope.importFile = files[0];
        }
      };

      $scope.cancelImport = function() {
        $scope.importFile = undefined;
        $rootScope.closeView();

        if ($rootScope.selectedLocation)
          $state.go("importUsers.inserted");
      };
    }
  ])
  .directive('uiSrefIf', function($compile) {
    return {
      scope: {
        val: '@uiSrefVal',
        if : '=uiSrefIf'
      },
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $element.removeAttr('ui-sref-if');
        $compile($element)($scope);

        $scope.$watch('if', function(bool) {
          if (bool) {
            $element.attr('ui-sref', $scope.val);
          } else {
            $element.removeAttr('ui-sref');
            $element.removeAttr('href');
          }
          $compile($element)($scope);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="importUsersController">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="table importLocationsCol">
        <div class="row headerRow titleBar">
          <div class="col-md-9"><i class="icon-users"></i>Import Users</div>
          <div class="col-md-3 importNewBtnDiv">
            <div class="btn btn-cancel importNewButton" ng-click="newImport()" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">
              <a ui-sref="importUsers.file" style="text-decoration: none !important; color: #585858;">New</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <h4>Past Imports</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <table class="table table-striped deptTable importTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="importNameCol">Location</th>
                <th class="importCountsCol">Update / New / Skip</th>
                <th class="importDateCol">Imported</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-show="loading && locations && locations.length == 0">
                <td colspan="3">
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <img class="spinner" src="content/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-hide="true">
                <td>&nbsp;
                  <!-- trick angular into making the next row white -->
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-repeat=" location in locations" ng-class="{selected: location.code == selectedLocation.code}" ng-show="locations && locations.length > 0" ng-click="viewImports(location)">
                <td class="importNameCol">{{location.name}} - {{location.city}}, {{location.state}}</td>
                <td class="importCountsCol">{{location.updated}} / {{location.inserted}} / {{location.skipped}}</td>
                <td class="importDateCol">{{location.timeStampUtc | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr ng-hide="loading || (locations && locations.length > 0)">
                <td colspan="3" class="text-center">No Imports Found.</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 paginationRow">
            <pagination total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="5" ng-show="totalItems > itemsPerPage || true" direction-links="false" boundary-links="false" rotate="false" ng-change="refresh()" class="pagination-sm pull-right"></pagination>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="table importViewCol" ng-show="selectedLocation != null || importing">
        <div class="row headerRow titleBar">
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <i class="icon-users"></i><span ng-show="importing">New</span><span ng-hide="importing">View</span> Import
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 text-right" ng-click="closeView()"><i class="icon-close"></i>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="editWorkOrder" style="padding-bottom: 0; border: 0;">
          <div class="tabBox">
            <div class="tabStrip">
              <div class="tab" ng-show="importing" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" ui-sref-active="thisTab">
                <a ui-sref="importUsers.file">File</a>
              </div>
              <div class="tab" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" ui-sref-active="thisTab" ng-disabled="importing">
                <a ui-sref-if="!importing" ui-sref-val="importUsers.inserted">Inserted</a>
              </div>
              <div class="tab" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" ui-sref-active="thisTab" ng-disabled="importing">
                <a ui-sref-if="!importing" ui-sref="importUsers.insertError">Inserted with Errors</a>
              </div>
              <div class="tab" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" ui-sref-active="thisTab" ng-disabled="importing">
                <a ui-sref-if="!importing" ui-sref="importUsers.updated">Updated</a>
              </div>
              <div class="tab" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" ui-sref-active="thisTab" ng-disabled="importing">
                <a ui-sref-if="!importing" ui-sref="importUsers.skipped">Skipped</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="importUsersDisplay" ui-view></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Because we use so many service calls I haven't tried to get this working in Plunker. It's not a show stopper since the page behaves as expected. It is an annoyance that I'd like to understand and eliminate. Also, my QA folks can then stop complaining to me about it :)

Thanks, Mike

Comment: is this the simplest example of your code that causes the problem? This seems like alot of code you are asking us to wade through...have you read the SO page [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Let me pare down the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks! if you take time to craft your question a bit more, the I bet you will get help :D

Comment: Guess I can't pare it down. The relevant parts are the <div class="col-md-7"> with the links in it near the bottom of the markup and the directive at the bottom of the JS. I put the rest of it in for completeness. The $stateProviders at the top of the JS are also relevant. I put this much stuff in because I find it frustrating in a good number of questions here that the questioner doesn't put in enough information and folks spend days asking questions in comments to get at the nub of the issue. So in hindsight I could have pared it down better and apologize for that.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to try :D I upvoted the question to help you get more exposure :D